# Array in soldity two dimensional array value

Tags: solidity

I study array in solidity ,when i write dynamic two dimensional and add value to array i get error why? and how to add value to array

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
contract myarray{
   
    uint[6] ipadPrice=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,1000];  // fixed size integer array with 6 elements
    uint[]  macPrice=[1100,2100,3100]; // dynamic array
    uint[2] ipadPricePro=[1500,2000]; // one dimensional fixed size array
    uint[] macPricePro=[2000,2500,3000]; //one dimensional dynamic array
    uint[][]ipadAirPrice=[1200,1400,1600,1800][8,6,8,4];

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```js
contract myarray {

    uint[][] ipadAirPrice = [[uint(1200),1400,1600,1800],[uint(8),6,8,4]];

    function addElement(uint256 subArrayIndex, uint256 element) public {
        ipadAirPrice[subArrayIndex].push(element);
    }

    function getElements() public view returns(uint[][] memory) {
        return ipadAirPrice;
    }
    
}
```

Notice how it's necessary to manually cast the first elements of the sub-arrays to a common type, because Solidity tries to use the small numbers you have in the array (8, 6, 8 4) as `uint8` and the big numbers (1200, 1400, etc) as the next type that can hold them, which would be `uint16`. Since `uint8` and `uint16` are not compatible, you need to cast at least the first element of each sub-array to a common element so you let Solidity know what is the type of each of those sub-elements.

Solidity compiler is not yet smart enough to handle that. Maybe in the future, it will.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to declare the array as uint256[][]?

Answer (score 0):

```
uint[][]ipadAirPrice=[1200,1400,1600,1800][8,6,8,4];
```

should be:

```
uint[][]ipadAirPrice=[[1200,1400,1600,1800],[8,6,8,4]];
```